# Mongoose .populate() doesn't populate whole user model

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am trying to use mongodb query `.populate()` to populate user data in my allocations response.
But i looks like it is not working. It is not populating user data but only id (take a look at response below). I have tride to use "user" or "users" but when i use "user" it return user as null

User model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;


const UserSchema = new Schema({

    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    allocations: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'allocation'
    }],
    admin: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },


});

module.exports = mongoose.model('users', UserSchema);
```

Allocations models

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;


const AllocationSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        default: 'New'
    },
    jan: {
        type: String,
        default: 0
    },
    feb: {
        type: String,
        default: 0
    },
    mar: {
        type: String,
        default: 0
    },
    apr: {
        type: String,
        default: 0
    },
    may: {
        type: String,
        default: 0
    },
    jun: {
        type: String,
        default: 0
    },
    jul: {
        type: String,
        default: 0
    },
    aug: {
        type: String,
        default: 0
    },
    sep: {
        type: String,
        default: 0
    },
    nov: {
        type: String,
        default: 0
    },
    oct: {
        type: String,
        default: 0
    },
    dec: {
        type: String,
        default: 0
    },



})


const AllocationsSchema = new Schema({

    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        refs: 'users'
    },
    year: {
        type: String,

    },
    allocations: [AllocationSchema],
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('allocation', AllocationsSchema);


exports.getAllUsersAndAllocations = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let users = await AllocationModel.find({
            year: "2019"
        }).populate(
            'user'
        )

        return res.json(users)
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error.message)
        return res.status(500).send('Server error')
    }
}
```

response:

```
{
        "_id": "5d76ceb0e1fa5c2b6f8f5bed",
        "user": "5d7671c446c7ba228ca1382b",
        "year": "2019",
        "allocations": [
            {
                "name": "New",
                "jan": "0",
                "feb": "0",
                "mar": "0",
                "apr": "0",
                "may": "0",
                "jun": "0",
                "jul": "0",
                "aug": "0",
                "sep": "0",
                "nov": "0",
                "oct": "0",
                "dec": "0",
                "_id": "5d76ceb3e1fa5c2b6f8f5bef"
            },
            {
                "name": "New",
                "jan": "0",
                "feb": "0",
                "mar": "0",
                "apr": "0",
                "may": "0",
                "jun": "0",
                "jul": "0",
                "aug": "0",
                "sep": "0",
                "nov": "0",
                "oct": "0",
                "dec": "0",
                "_id": "5d76ceb0e1fa5c2b6f8f5bee"
            }
        ],
        "date": "2019-09-09T22:14:08.573Z",
        "__v": 1
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it may just be a typo in your AllocationSchema. Under 'User' you have written `refs: 'users'` when it should be `ref: 'users'` i.e. 'ref' instead of 'refs'